# How to access ReactQuill api?

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

I need to access `<ReactQuill/>` with button.
For instance I click buttons and remove or save content of `ReactQuill`.
But i cannot understand how to properly get access of functions of `ReactQuill` in React.
In example they propose to use `quill` variable to access functions of this component.
For instance remove content of component `quill.setContents([{ insert: '\n' }])`
But the question is how to properly define it?

I tried to do it like in some examples but it didn't work.

```
const [quill, setQuill] = useState(null);

       <ReactQuill
        style={{height: '45vh', marginBottom: '1px'}}
        ref={(el) => {
         setQuill(el)
        }}
      />
 
     <Button type="primary" icon={<DeleteOutlined />} 
       onClick={()=> 
        quill.setContents([{ insert: '\n' }])}
      >Clear</Button>
```

Maybe anyone knows how to properly define their quill variable?
I was going through their documentation but, it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ref instead of useState

```
const quill = useRef();

<ReactQuill
    style={{height: '45vh', marginBottom: '1px'}}
    ref={quill}
/>

<Button type="primary" icon={<DeleteOutlined />} 
    onClick={()=> 
    quill.current.editor.insertText(0, "text")}
>Clear</Button>
```

Comment: Hello @Kanti I used same but not able to get the ref getting like this 
{current:null}
`<ReactQuill
          ref={quillRef}
          modules={modules}
          formats={formats}
          value={editorValue}
          {...restProps}
          onChange={handleEditorChange}
        />`

Comment: Hi, @vishalgajera can you please provide more details about the issues you're trying to solve, so I can help you address them?

Comment: here I created question please if you can check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77541282/react-quill-quill-js5824-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceede)